# No funciona post con ajax y yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Tengo dos datapicker con fecha inicial y fecha final  en un form y pretendo que al cambiar la fecha final me muestre en forma automatica la diferencia entre dìas de las dos fechas en un input text . Pero no funciona .
La vista :

```
$('#fechafin').change(function(){

     fechafin = $("#fechafin").val();
     fechainicio = $("#fechainicio").val();

     $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "?r=clasificado%2Fcontardias",
         data: {
            fechafin: fechafin,
            fechainicio: fechainicio,
         }
     })

     .done(function( aux ) {
        $("#nfechas").val(aux['nfechas']);
        }
     )
});
```

En el controlador:

```
public function actionContardias(){

        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
             $out1 = "";
        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) 
        {
            $fechainicial = $_POST['fechainicio'];
            $fechafinal = $_POST['fechafin'];

            $out2 = (strtotime($fechafinal)-strtotime($fechainicial))/86400;
            $out2= floor($out2);
            if (empty($out2)) {
                $out1 = ['nfechas' => ''];
            } else {
                $out1 = ['nfechas' => $out2];
            }
        }

        return  $out1;
}
```

Si le hago un render a una pagina distinta me envia el json con el valor adecuado , pero sobre esta vista no muestra nada . Si alguno me indica el error . Gracias

Comment: ¿Verificaste que entra a este bloque: `$('#fechafin').change(function(){`? ¿Verificaste lo que hay en `aux`. Haz pruebas de consola. Puede que esto esté mal: `aux['nfechas']`, ya que devuelves un array JSON, no un objeto JSON, por tanto, la lectura debería ser así: `aux[0].nfechas`, prueba de este modo: **`$("#nfechas").val(aux[0].nfechas);`** Ten en cuenta que en el primer caso no se mostrará nada, porque asignas una cadena vacía `$out1 = ['nfechas' => ''];` Siempre conviene hacer pruebas de consola para depurar el código.

Comment: Estoy con @A.Cedano , deberías depurar qué valor tiene `aux` con un `console.log(aux)`. También vendría bien saber cómo configuras las rutas en Yii, quizá no tienes `clasificado/contardias` bien configurada. También nos vendría bien saber qué te aparece en el inspector de tráfico del navegador (si nos indicas cuál usas te podremos decir cómo usarlo). PD: @A.Cedano , los arrays en JSON sólo pueden tener índices numéricos. PHP genera una clase JSON (`{}`) cuando una matriz tiene índices alfanuméricos, por lo que un valor en PHP `[ 'indice' => 'valor' ]` será `{ 'indice': 'valor' }` en JSON.

Comment: Gracias por responder . Ajusté al modo recomendado y sigue sin mostrar nada . Los navegadores utilizados son firefox y chrome . La ruta la verifiqué y está correcta

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques la vida, intenta sacar la diferencia de días con [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).
Hice algo similar y funciona perfecto

```
$('#fechafin').on('change', function(){
    var fInicio = $("#fechafin").val();
    var fFinal = $("#fechainicio").val();
    var a = moment(fInicio, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var b = moment(fFinal, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var days = b.diff(a, 'days');
    alert(days + ' días de diferencia entre las 2 fechas');
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder . Me indica por favor como implementarlo para que funcione .

Comment: Hice la modificación del código y quedaría de la siguiente manera. Solo descarga la librería de moment.js e implementala como cualquier plugin de jquery o js